# AnyDesk is not working before login from remote PC (manually)

Tags: 20.04, wayland, anydesk

My Ubuntu version is 20.04. I am using AnyDesk for remote access to my lab pc. When I am trying to connect to my remote pc (the lab one) from my personal pc, I am getting some challenges. Like,

I am getting a `remote display server is not supported (e.g. Wayland)` error at the time of login from personal to the lab one.

Then I `disabled` the `Wayland` based on [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and now I am getting `desk_rt_ipc_error`.

However, once I log in from my remote PC, then I can use AnyDesk from my personal one.

I have gone through several posts, but not getting any idea to solve the issues.

I appreciate your time and support.

Comment: Hi, I seem to be having the same problem but on a Linux Mint box ... How did u solve this ?

Comment: Nope, I didn't get the solution!

Comment: Thanks. I just switched to NoMachine - Works great. If you behind a office firewall, use port forwarding unless your firewall / router supports upnp.

Comment: Thank for the information

Comment: @MarcoZen Based on your suggestion, I also switched NoMachine. But, unfortunately, servers are not connecting! Could you tell me how I have to use port forwarding?

Comment: Hi ... You may have to open a question and list  yr info for me / others to help. In the meantime - U are behind a firewall ? Will the admin cooperate with a port fwd or you have to do it on yr own ?

Comment: Okay, I will do that. I have to do myself!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by going into the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file and do this change:

```
[daemon]
        # Enabling automatic login
        AutomaticLoginEnable=true
        AutomaticLogin=$USERNAME
```

and don't forget to also put the following in the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: I have both fix implemented and still getting the same message :(
[daemon] # Enabling automatic login AutomaticLoginEnable=true AutomaticLogin=$USERNAME
and
WaylandEnable=false Same problem connecting from Win10 or Android.
It only happens if Ubuntu just restarted and no login done yet... meaning no remote support in case of Ubuntu restart
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1- Install `lightdm` display manager:

```
sudo apt -y install lightdm
```

or

```
sudo dnf install lightdm lightdm-gtk
```

2- Enable `lightdm` and disable `gdm`

```
sudo systemctl enable lightdm.service && sudo systemctl disable gdm.service
```

3- Reboot.

After you finished, you can switch to gdm again by:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service && sudo systemctl enable gdm.service
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit file with `nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
2. Uncomment the following

   ```
   [daemon]
   # Enabling automatic login
   AutomaticLoginEnable=true
   AutomaticLogin=$USERNAME
   WaylandEnable=false
   ```
3. Make sure you change $USERNAME with actual username like the following

   ```
    AutomaticLogin=fouaduser
   ```

   Then REBOOT
4. this will enable auto login for your ubuntu user while startup without asking for password, you can adjust timeout the idle power with 1 minute to lock ubuntu server again
5. with this solution you can user Anydesk without remotely issues

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer from @Sajjad worked for me. The only problem was that I could not turn back to gdm using

> sudo systemctl disable lightdm.service && sudo systemctl enable gdm.service

So after this last command and booting up again, I had to log in from the terminal. To get the UI running again I used:

```
systemctl start gdm
```

And to turn back the gdm as default:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

If gdm is "stuck", when you try to set it as default, you can try using:

```
systemctl status gdm.service
systemctl force-reload gdm.service
```

Additionally, you can try adding `/np` after your Anydesk remote device ID to check-in.